# Why signal deteriorate in half-duplex UART communication in long wire (6 meter)?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, mosfet, serial, uart

I am doing project on half-duplex UART communication between two AVR microcontrollers. I am using n-mosfet based push pull circuit in both transmitter and receiver side. 3.3 V signals transmission is okay for the short distance but for longer distance (6 meter), signals deteriorate (shape of pulse becomes pointed and voltage drops) and signal is not anymore valid on receiver side. I need to setup the communication at least 10 meter. Circuit I am implementing is given below. It needs to be low power.
[image]

Comment: At 6m you should try RS232 for your physical layer. Just get a MAX232 and use it on both ends. RS232 has a range of roughly 10m. If you need to do better (either high bit rate or longer distances) then try RS485. Get a MAX481 and your signal can go up to 100m.

Comment: thanks for response but i think MAX232 can only be used for full duplex communication.And i want to transmit Rx and TX from single wire.I assumption for signal deteriorate for increase in length of wire is due to capacitance and inductance of wire.I am actually looking for some modification in  above circuit so that such behavior can be reduce.

Comment: You have a return/ground connection between them?

Comment: Try using two wires twisted together ("twisted pair") for signal and ground.

Comment: Yes i have ground connection between them.I am using stereo audio wire (power,data and ground) between the microcontrollers. Data and voltage wire is shielded by ground wire.  So twisting the cable is not possible.

Comment: @starblue, would twisting the signal/ground together increase the capacitance to ground since capacitance is inversely proportional to the distance between "plates"?

Comment: RS485 can be used half duplex. See the datasheet for MAX481. As a bonus it can also be used in a multidrop configuration meaning you can have more than 2 nodes connected to a single line. You'll still need a mechanism to prevent everyone transmitting at once but that can be done in software.

Comment: As a side note. I'm writing comments instead of an answer because my answer doesn't answer the question "why". I'm just giving the "how". If it's OK with you for an answer to not answer your main question I can write up my recommendation for RS485 in an actual answer.

Comment: Actually my question is why as well as how. So i appreciate your suggestion. But i am actually thinking about using UART because basic communication is already ready.

Comment: The main problem is usually inductance, which is reduced when the wires are closer together. In your case I think the resistance of the audio wire is too high.

Comment: That is not push-pull.  It is just open drain with a pullup resistor.  A 10Kohm resistor can't properly drive long cables with a much lower characteristic impedance unless the bit rate is very low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a higher transmission voltage (I've seen 12V used successfully with a very similar half-duplex bus in a commercial product with an operating range of several hundred metres) and smaller pullup resistors (2K2-4K7).  Also, don't expect high data rates; I'd suggest 4.8kbps as a maximum (the commercial product uses 4kbps).

Comment: Thanks markt, When i increase the voltage and lower the pullup register , wave form is better in ltspice but i stil need to test it on board.But the rising edge doesnot have sharp edge like falling edge what can be reason behind it and is it possible to solve this behavior . In the link below you can find schematic file in ltspice if u like to look at it.https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgs42t1w86d7yqp/singlewire.asc

Comment: The rising edge is "lazy" because it's not being driven, it's just the pullup resistor dragging it up to the rail voltage.  If you want a sharp(er) rising edge, then you'll need a to use either a "push-pull" driver or a lower value pullup resistor.  Both of these have engineering costs; a smaller resistor will consume more power, and the push-pull driver is not as simple as it might sound because it requires an undriven (high impedance) state for reception to work.